# Runtime errors when coding OpenCV programs using codeBlocks in linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, codeblocks

When I try to compile a C++ program which uses the openCV library in CodeBlocks it gives me a runtime error :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_calib3d.so.2.2: 
cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

This is in spite of the fact that I have added all the required libraries using linker settings for the Code Blocks IDE (including the one named libopencv_calib3d.so.2.2 which is a symbolic link).

However I'm able to compile the program using the command line by issuing the command :

```
g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world \
      -I /usr/local/include/opencv -L /usr/local/lib 
      \ -lm -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux
```

Can somebody advise me on how I can get to run the same using Code Blocks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file libopencv_calib3d.so.2.2 is part of OpenCV 2.2. There is, however, no libcv, libhighgui or libcvaux part of OpenCV 2.2. This means that your g++ call links against **another** version of OpenCV.

To link against OpenCV 2.2, you would need flags like `-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann`.

You should also not put them in manually, but instead use

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/share/opencv/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` hello-world.cpp -o hello-world
```

Comment: Thanks! but I think the flags worked for me manually when i used g++. However I'm trying to compile my code using codeblocks IDE. So is there any way to permanently associate libcv, libhighgui , libcvaux etc with OpenCV 2.2 in CodeBlocks?

Comment: No, because these libs are *not* part of OpenCV 2.2 and you should get rid of them! They are from an older version of OpenCV and they will only cause you trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing a reasonably up-to-date version of OpenCV for Linux, 2.4.9 for example, at this time of writing, appears to build with the current version of gcc that I have (4.8.2).   There are a few steps you need to complete in order to get a simple OpenCV example up and running in Code::Blocks.  The OpenCV documentation tells you to create a build directory within your OpenCV root directory and run cmake, make, sudo make install etc in order to generate the libraries your project may need to link to, including the libopencv_calib3d.so you mention:

[image]

This blog posting gives explanations on how to install OpenCV and configure it's use for Code::Blocks in Ubuntu Linux environments:

http://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/using-opencv-in-codeblocks-in-linux/